# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'amount' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am working on wiring up the ExpressJS part of a Stripe payment system. I wanted to pass some properties dynamically, such as `amount` and `description`.

I have these three different components that represent the products: `<SunnySampler />`, `<Grasses />`, and `<HalfPound />`.

In them I pass the `amount` and `description` props like so: `<Grasses amount={1500} description="Tray" />`.

Then on my `StripCheckout` component I pass the amount and description from the props given to the above components. And I also pass the `amount` and `description` to the `handleToken` function:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import StripeCheckout from "react-stripe-checkout";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as actions from "../actions";

class SunnySampler extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <StripeCheckout
          name='Microurb Farms'
          description={this.props.description}
          amount={this.props.amount}
          shippingAddress
          billingAddress={false}
          zipCode={true}
          token={(token) =>
            this.props.handleToken(
              token,
              this.props.amount,
              this.props.description
            )
          }
          stripeKey={process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_KEY}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, actions)(SunnySampler);
```

This is what my action creator looks like:

```
export const handleToken = (token, amount, description) => async (dispatch) => {
  const res = await axios.post("/api/stripe", { token, amount, description });

  dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER, payload: res.data });
};
```

So that was the client side, now in on the server side I have a `billingRoute.js` file that looks like this:

```
const keys = require("../config/keys");
const stripe = require("stripe")(keys.stripeSecretKey);

module.exports = (app) => {
  app.post("/api/stripe", async (req, res) => {
    // const token = req.body.data.token;
    const amount = req.body.data.amount;
    const description = req.body.data.description;
    const charge = await stripe.charges.create({
      amount: amount,
      currency: "usd",
      description: description,
      source: req.body.id,
    });

    console.log(charge);
  });
};
```

Unfortunately, I am getting the following error in terminal:

> (node:99567) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read
> property 'amount' of undefined [0]     at
> /Projects/NodeCRA/routes/billingRoutes.js:7:34 [0]
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request]
> (/Projects/NodeCRA/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
> [0]     at next
> (/Projects/NodeCRA/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
> [0]     at Route.dispatch
> (/Projects/NodeCRA/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
> [0]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request]
> (/Projects/NodeCRA/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
> [0]     at
> /Projects/NodeCRA/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
> [0]     at Function.process_params
> (/Projects/NodeCRA/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
> [0]     at next
> (/Projects/NodeCRA/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
> [0]     at SessionStrategy.strategy.pass
> (/Projects/NodeCRA/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:343:9)
> [0]     at
> /Projects/NodeCRA/node_modules/passport/lib/strategies/session.js:69:12
> [0]     at pass
> (/Projects/NodeCRA/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:337:31)
> [0]     at deserialized
> (/Projects/NodeCRA/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:349:7)
> [0]     at
> /Projects/NodeCRA/services/passport.js:14:5 [0]
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
> [0] (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was
> created)

I thought maybe `token`, `amount` and `description` needed to be passed as properties to the `data` object inside the action creator but that gives me a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Destructuring is what resolved the error here at the end of the day and also passing in `amount` to the arrow function inside of `handleToken`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import StripeCheckout from "react-stripe-checkout";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as actions from "../actions";

class SunnySampler extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <StripeCheckout
          name='Microurb Farms'
          description={this.props.description}
          amount={this.props.amount}
          shippingAddress
          billingAddress={false}
          zipCode={true}
          token={(token, amount, description) =>
            this.props.handleToken(
              token,
              this.props.amount,
              this.props.description
            )
          }
          stripeKey={process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_KEY}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, actions)(SunnySampler);
```

And here is the destructuring part in my `billingsRoute.js`:

```
const keys = require("../config/keys");
const stripe = require("stripe")(keys.stripeSecretKey);

module.exports = (app) => {
  app.post("/api/stripe", async (req, res) => {
    const { amount, token, description } = req.body;
    console.log(req.body.description);
    // const description = req.body.data.description;
    const charge = await stripe.charges.create({
      amount: amount,
      currency: "usd",
      description: description,
      source: token.id,
    });

    console.log(charge);
  });
};
```